# Javascript arbitrary element of an array based on a "string" seed

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to javascript. I'm looking for a javascript function to get an arbitrary element of a given array based on a given string input.

A random(seed) function would be useful but I can't find one. 
Or maybe a way to xor hash the bytes in a string.

I can't use jquery, and I'm hoping for an answer that's relatively short.

Edit for examples:

```
var myArray = ["foo", "bar", "24", "asdf"];
```

the signature would look like

```
function ArbitraryElement(arr, seed)
```

and outputs would look something like:

```
ArbitraryElement(myArray, "what") // "foo"
ArbitraryElement(myArray, "that") // "24"
ArbitraryElement(myArray, "what") // "foo"
ArbitraryElement(myArray, "boo")  // "24"
ArbitraryElement(myArray, "cat")  // "asdf"
// etc...
```

Comment: Example string inputs, arrays, and expected outputs, please.

Comment: That's the word, deterministic. This function should be deterministic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sum the char codes with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), IE9 native and IE8 and below with shim included in link:

```
function ArbitraryElement(arr, seed) {
    seed = (seed || '') + "xx"; // ensure a seed that can be reduced
    var charCodes = seed.split('').reduce(function(a, b, i) {
        return (i == 1 ? a.charCodeAt(0) : +a) + b.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    return arr[charCodes % arr.length]
}
```

EDIT:

Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/sqA6Z/

Comment: For posterity, if seed is 0 or 1 characters, it returns "undefined". I simply appended "xx" to the seed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would like to have this "array lookup" be deterministic, in that passing in the same string would result in the same array index being accessed?

If so, I recommend performing a hash on the string, and then modding it by the size of the array.

[You can use this to compute an MD5 hash](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/)

```
var foo = getHash(inputString);
var index = foo % myArray.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function return a random element from your array (no seed is needed):

```
function getRandomItem(input) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * input.length);
    return(input[index]);
}

var myArray = ["foo", "bar", "24", "asdf"];
getRandomItem(myArray);
getRandomItem(myArray);
getRandomItem(myArray);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/J5QKE/

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking to use a seed to make a deterministic arbitrary selection. Not a random selection. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: What is "deterministic arbitrary"?  Never heard of that.

Comment: There should be a comma in there. They're the usual English meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted answer, although I prefer a simpler recursion alternative.

```
const charSum = (str) =>
!str.length ? 0 : str.charCodeAt(0) + charSum(str.substr(1));
```